# Is there an equivalent function in C/C++ to GNU-R which()?

Tags: c++, c, r

Let me explain what the 'which' function does:

From GNU-R help:

> which indices are TRUE?
>
> Give the ‘TRUE’ indices of a logical object, allowing for array indices.

or showing some code: (GNU-R starts counting indices with 1)

```
> x <- c(1,2,3,1,3,5);
> which(x == 1);
[1] 1 4
> which(x == 3);
[1] 3 5
> ll <- c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,NA,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE);
> which(ll);
[1] 1 3 7
```

Does anyone know a similar function in C/C++?

Thanks for your help

rinni

Comment: [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) or [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) depending on what you want to do with it. (Or any of several other library calls)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to understand that [R](http://www.r-project.org) is vectorised, whereas C first and foremost works on individual atomistic data pieces: a single `int`, `double`, ...

With C++, you can look into STL algorithms with which you approach this.

Lastly, at the R and C++ intersection, our [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) package has some vectorized operations in C++ which mimic some operations; see the [Rcpp-sugar](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-sugar.pdf) pdf vignette for more (and/or some of our talks on Rcpp).

Comment: your are absolutely right. My fist approach was quite R centered. Guess I have to try it for am C++ point of view.

Answer (score 4):

Create a functor object that you can initialize with the match value, and iterator over your list using `std::for_each`.  So for example:

```
vector<int> values;
//fill your vector with values;

struct match_functor
{
    vector<int> value_array;
    int match_value;

    match_functor(int value): match_value(value) {}

    void operator() (int input_value)
    {
        if(match_value == input_value)
            value_array.push_back(input_value);
    }
};

match_functor matches(1);
std::for_each(values.begin(), values.end(), matches);
```

Now your result value array can be accessed using `matches.value_array[INDEX]`.

As an alternative, if you simply want to have the indicies of the original vector, rather than the actual values, then you can do something like this for your functor object:

```
struct match_functor
{
    vector<int> index_array;
    int match_value;
    int index;

    match_functor(int value): match_value(value), index(0) {}

    void operator() (int input_value)
    {
        if(match_value == input_value)
            index_array.push_back(index);

        index++;
    }
};

match_functor matches(1);
matches = std::for_each(values.begin(), values.end(), matches);
```

Now `matches.index_array[INDEX]` will hold the indicies of the orignal vector that match the value `1`, and not the actual values from the original vector.

Comment: your first code snippet is just a more complicated substitute of `std::remove_copy_if`.

Comment: It's not removing any values though ... it's making a copy of the desired value N times for the number of occurances in the original vector.

Comment: @Jason Yes, it copies the values from the input vector to some other, thereby removing (not copying) any values that don't conform to some predicate. That's what `std::remove_copy_if` does.

Comment: @Christian Rau: Yep, you're right ... sorry, I was thinking of `std::remove_if` which does modify the values in the iterable container/array

Comment: Thanks for your snippets they helped my a lot. But as Dirk said one has to take off his R glasses and put the C++ ones on. I'm on a quite different approach now.

Answer (score 2):

the algorithm `std::find_if` should do the trick - in conjunction with a loop I should add.